# Tag selection autocomplete dialog crashes my browser(s)

Tags: bug, tag-autocomplete

About one time out of three, when I start typing a tag name and launch the autocompletion script, the script crashes with this error (on firefox):

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let
>   the script continue.
>
> Script:
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/aja…ibs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3

This happens on all sites on the network, on both firefox (40.0 and previous versions) and chromium (45.0.2454.85). There seems to be no pattern to it, the same seed word will sometimes work fine and sometimes crash. On firefox, I need to wait until the error above occurs (and can't use my browser in the meantime) and on chromium I need to close the offending tab.

This is on 64 bit Debian. It may or may not be related to [this other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266425/203101).

I just checked and this doesn't seem to (so far) occur with another account on the same machine, which would suggest that it is somehow a problem on my end. Any ideas what could cause this? It can't be an extension issue since it occurs in both firefox and chromium. What would those two share that could produce this issue?