# Browser asks for confirmation when submitting a question or answer

Tags: bug

Every time I try to post a question or answer, my browser pops up a confirmation dialog:

[image: error dialogue]

I need to choose "leave page" to continue. If I chose "stay on this page" and hit "submit" again, I am told that my post is a duplicate. In other words, the post was successfully submitted the first time, before the confirmation dialog.

I can confirm this by opening the page in a new tab and I can see my answer there despite being told that I haven't actually posted it. This happens on both firefox (40.0 and previous versions) and chromium (45.0.2454.85) and on all sites of the network.

Both browsers running on a 64 bit Debian. This may or may not be related to [this other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266424/203101).

This is what I see in the Network tab of chromium's dev tools when submitting:

[image]

and after clicking on "leave page":

[image]

I just checked and this doesn't occur with another account on the same machine, which would suggest that it is somehow a problem on my end. Any ideas what could cause this? It can't be an extension issue since it occurs in both firefox and chromium. What would those two share that could produce this issue?

Comment: Check in your browser's dev tools, in Network tab - do you see any errors loading any resource?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no errors when the popup appears. What I guess is an error (the red line) after submitting, when the submitted question page is loaded.

Comment: Do you use a proxy? Did you try with HTTPS and no proxy? Did you try without any extension — it could be an extension that you've installed on both browsers?

Comment: @Gilles No proxy, no, and https makes no difference. However, I just tested in an incognito tab (so, no extensions) and it doesn't happen. Damn. I'll have to find out which one is causing this then. It is almost certainly a stackapps script since those are the ones I have on both browsers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a user script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was my fault. Please refer to [Close Reason Editor on Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/4483/) for updates on this bug.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Gilles who pointed me in the right direction, I managed to figure out that this was caused by a buggy stackapps script:

[Close Reason Editor: Customize your off-topic close reasons](https://stackapps.com/q/4483/17253)

This script caused both this bug and the one about the [tag completion dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266424/203101). The latter [had already been reported](https://stackapps.com/a/6349/17253) and is apparently fixed in the newer version of the script. This bug,however, still persists in the new version.

Removing the script solved both issues.

Comment: And that's the reason I never used user scripts for Stack Exchange and probably never will. Unless I'll write them myself. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am sorry for making you feel that way. But please don't blame userscripts. They are awesome. It was just me being dumb.

Comment: @Antony no worry, really not you. Just me. :)